# How do I get Wacom Tablet drivers to initiate with new Intuos Pro series?

Tags: drivers, wacom, input-devices

Just as the question says.

This issue happens under Ubuntu 13.x (and also Linux Mint). When Wacom decided to re-release their Wacom Intuos Pro series, the current linux-wacom drivers were no good, so I had to go manually build and install the `input-wacom-0.20.0` drivers to replace the obsolete `wacom.ko` driver so that it will recognise Wacom Intuos Pro PTH-4xx series, previously known as Wacom Intuos 5 series.

Thing is, the drivers are working and are recognised, however no input is received when I got to use my Intuos Pro PTH-451/K, that is until I got plug in my OLD tablet, my Wacom BambooFun CTE-450/W just to get the drivers to actually work from plugging it into the system so that my PTH-451/K tablet will work.

I don't know why or how, but just plugging in my old wacom tablet initiates the drivers. I won't have my old Wacom BambooFun forever, so I just wanna know a work fix to make it so that the Wacom driver initiates whenever my Wacom Intuos Pro Pen and Touch in plugged in my system.

- I can just plug in my BambooFun for a couple seconds and safely remove while being able to use my other tablet just fine, but this really isn't ideal, and need a permanent fix I could add to either a script or modify to the kernel when it loads the drivers at boot.

Comment: Bumping the question up.

Comment: If you have no issues with graphic cards, update to Ubuntu 14.04. In that version Intuos pro version works by default ;)